# How to read REG_MULTI_SZ from windows Registry in C++ Builder IDE?

Tags: registry, c++builder

Getting error of `Access violation at address xxxxxx in module (myApp.exe) Read of address 00000000`, when i tried to read Registry value of type **REG_MULTI_SZ**.

I want to read REG_MULTI_SZ datatype from windows registry key, and add the results to my `TListBox` Component, here is the code i use to do that:

```
void TSQLInstanceMain::GetSQLInstances(TStrings *AStrings)
{

    HKEY hkey;
    DWORD vType;
    DWORD vLen;
    DWORD buffer;
    wchar_t *p;
    UnicodeString RegKeyName  = L"\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\";
    UnicodeString RegKeyValue = "InstalledInstances";

    try {
        if ( RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, RegKeyName.w_str(), 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hkey) == ERROR_SUCCESS )
        {
            SetLastErrorEx(RegQueryValueExW(hkey, RegKeyValue.w_str(), NULL, &vType, NULL, &vLen), NULL);

            if ( GetLastError() == ERROR_SUCCESS && vType == REG_MULTI_SZ  )
            {
                buffer = (DWORD)GetMemory(vLen);
                RegQueryValueExW(hkey, RegKeyValue.w_str(), NULL, NULL, PByte(buffer), &vLen);
                p = (wchar_t*)buffer;
                AStrings->Clear();
                while ( &p != 0x0 )
                {

                 AStrings->Add(p);
                 p += lstrlen(p)+1;

                }

            }
        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        FreeMemory(&buffer);
    }

}
```

**Note:** I found this code in this [article](http://delphi-kb.blogspot.com/2006/05/read-registry-entry-of-type-regmultisz.html) and translated it to C++ as best as i could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AV error message is telling you that a NULL pointer is being read from.

One error I see in your code that could cause that is `while ( &p != 0x0 )`.  Your loop is checking the memory address of the `p` pointer itself, not the data it is pointing at.  As such, your loop will not terminate correctly when the pointer reaches the end of the string data.

Your loop should be `while ( *p != 0 )` instead (in Delphi, `p^` is a pointer dereference),

You should also over-allocate your `buffer` to include your own null terminator, as `RegQueryValueExW()` DOES NOT guarantee that string data is null-terminated.  Apps that store string data in the Registry are *supposed* to include a null terminator in the stored data, but many buggy apps exist that don't actually do that.  `RegQueryValueExW()` just returns the raw data exactly as it was saved, so the data you read MAY not be properly null-terminated, so append your own terminator, just in case:

```
wchar_t *buffer; // <-- not DWORD!
...
buffer = (wchar_t*) GetMemory(vLen + sizeof(wchar_t));
...
p = buffer;
...
FreeMemory(buffer); // <-- no &!
```

Alternatively, use `RegGetValueW()` instead, as it will append a null terminator for you if one is missing.

Lastly, you are leaking the `HKEY` that `RegOpenKeyExW()` returns.  You need to call `RegCloseKey()` when you are done using the `HKEY`.

With all of that said, try this instead:

```
#include <vector>

void TSQLInstanceMain::GetSQLInstances(TStrings *AStrings)
{
    HKEY hkey;
    DWORD vType;
    DWORD vLen = 0;
    std::vector<BYTE> buffer;
    wchar_t *p;

    const wchar_t *RegKeyName  = L"\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\";
    const wchar_t *RegKeyValue = L"InstalledInstances";

    if ( RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, RegKeyName, 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hkey) == ERROR_SUCCESS )
    {
        try
        {
            if ( (RegQueryValueExW(hkey, RegKeyValue, NULL, &vType, NULL, &vLen) == ERROR_SUCCESS) && (vType == REG_MULTI_SZ) )
            {
                vLen += sizeof(wchar_t);
                buffer.resize(vLen);
                RegQueryValueExW(hkey, RegKeyValue, NULL, &vType, &buffer[0], &vLen);
                p = (wchar_t*) &buffer[0];

                AStrings->BeginUpdate();
                try
                {
                    AStrings->Clear();
                    while ( *p != 0 )
                    {
                        AStrings->Add(p);
                        p += (lstrlenW(p) + 1);
                    }
                }
                __finally
                {
                    AStrings->EndUpdate();
                }
            }
        }
        __finally
        {
            RegCloseKey(hKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Or:

```
#include <vector>

void TSQLInstanceMain::GetSQLInstances(TStrings *AStrings)
{
    HKEY hkey;
    DWORD vLen = 0;
    std::vector<BYTE> buffer;
    wchar_t *p;

    const wchar_t *RegKeyName  = L"\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\";
    const wchar_t *RegKeyValue = L"InstalledInstances";

    if ( RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, RegKeyName, 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hkey) == ERROR_SUCCESS )
    {
        try
        {
            if ( (RegGetValueW(hkey, NULL, RegKeyValue, RRF_RT_REG_MULTI_SZ, NULL, NULL, &vLen) == ERROR_SUCCESS) )
            {
                buffer.resize(vLen);
                RegGetValueW(hkey, NULL, RegKeyValue, RRF_RT_REG_MULTI_SZ, NULL, &buffer[0], &vLen);
                p = (wchar_t*) &buffer[0];

                AStrings->BeginUpdate();
                try
                {
                    AStrings->Clear();
                    while ( *p != 0 )
                    {
                        AStrings->Add(p);
                        p += (lstrlenW(p) + 1);
                    }
                }
                __finally
                {
                    AStrings->EndUpdate();
                }
            }
        }
        __finally
        {
            RegCloseKey(hKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however this fixed the memory error, but it didn't get any values from that registry key, i checked the key again in **regedit** and value exists, tried to run the application **as administrator** same nothing.

Comment: @Abdennour did you step through the code in the debugger to see what it is actually doing? Did you verify that `RegOpenKeyExW()` is actually opening the key? Did you verify that `RegGetValueW()`/`RegGetValueW()` is  returning `ERROR_SUCCESS`? Did you verify the format of the returned data buffer is a proper double-null-terminated list?